# Where actually is the syntax error in my github actions yml file

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, github-api

I am actually implementing CI/CD for my application. I want to start the application automatically using pm2. So I am getting the syntax error on line 22.

This is my yml file
[image]

This is the error I am getting on github

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like the code in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the syntax here is related to how you used the `-` symbol.

With Github actions, you need at least a `run` or `uses` field inform for each step inside your job, at the same level of the `name` field (which is not mandarory), otherwise the github interpreter will return an error.

Here, from line 22, you used something like this:

```yaml
- name: ...
  - run: ...
  - run: ...
  - run: ...
```

So there are two problems:

- First, the `name` and the `run` field aren't at the same yaml level.
- Second, your step with the `name` field doesn't have a `run` or `uses` field associated with it (you need at least one of them).

The correct syntax should be:

```yaml
- name: ...
  run: ...
- run: ...
- run: ...
```

[Reference about workflow syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsteps)

Comment: Do you know where to find the error line on the GitActions user interface? I'm really frustrated that GitHub won't point out where the problem is. I see only: 
`every step must define a 'uses' or 'run' key`

Comment: In that case, it's probably a `-` in a wrong location (in front of `name`, `with`, `env` or something else... without `run` or `uses` fields associated). Generally, the proper Github UI when you open the workflow file should indicate the line where the error occurs.